# Getting exception : selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. here i have used Localthread<webdriver> for parallel execution

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

**Got below exception :
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()? Here i have used LocalThread for parallel test execution ,but while running multiple test within a class in one thread(not parallel execution)
First test cases ran successfully and second and third got failed  **

```html
Console Output:

[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Afsar\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--442788521\testng-customsuite.xml

****** In Before Method init method *********
Driver instanceis created and  set current local thread
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 41879
Only local connections are allowed.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Oct 22, 2017 5:03:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Set current thread method is called ..
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
*********Running first Test Case *********
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
**** Executing Logine Action *********
URL is sent succesfully..
Clicked on the Sign -on button 
User name Entered 
Password entered 
Sign -in clicked 
****** Executing Register Action *********
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
Register button is found 
PASSED : First test case : Login Successful..
****** In After Method tear down *********
Removing driver instance from current thread and closing all sesions
driver.quite called 
****** In Before Method init method *********
Driver instanceis created and  set current local thread
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 47720
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 22, 2017 5:03:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Set current thread method is called ..
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
*********Running second Test Case *********
**** Executing Logine Action *********
URL is sent succesfully..
****** In After Method tear down *********
Removing driver instance from current thread and closing all sesions
driver.quite called 
****** In Before Method init method *********
Driver instanceis created and  set current local thread
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 25049
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 22, 2017 5:03:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Set current thread method is called ..
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
Get curent thread method is called ..
Current thread id :1 thread name is :main
*********Running third  Test Case *********
**** Executing Logine Action *********
URL is sent succesfully..
****** In After Method tear down *********
Removing driver instance from current thread and closing all sesions
driver.quite called 
Current thread removed and clearcurrentDriver() called.. ..
PASSED: LoginFunctionality
        This is first test same as first 
FAILED: LoginFunctionality1
        This is second test same as first 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'AFSAR-PC', ip: '192.168.0.100', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:131)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:410)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:246)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.click(Unknown Source)
 at com.afsar.framework.pageobjects.MercuryToursHomePage.clickRegister(MercuryToursHomePage.java:58)
 at com.afsar.framework.actions.MercuryHomePage_Action.Login_Action(MercuryHomePage_Action.java:13)
 at com.afsar.framework.tests.LoginTest.LoginFunctionality1(LoginTest.java:56)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

FAILED: LoginFunctionality2
        This is third test same as first 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'AFSAR-PC', ip: '192.168.0.100', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:131)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:410)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:246)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.click(Unknown Source)
 at com.afsar.framework.pageobjects.MercuryToursHomePage.clickRegister(MercuryToursHomePage.java:58)
 at com.afsar.framework.actions.MercuryHomePage_Action.Login_Action(MercuryHomePage_Action.java:13)
 at com.afsar.framework.tests.LoginTest.LoginFunctionality2(LoginTest.java:67)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
 at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@49e4cb85: 407 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter@5594a1b5: 75 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@6e8dacdf: 19 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1134affc: 373 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 27 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@2f7c7260: 118 ms
```

```html
Login Test :

public class LoginTest{

 private  WebDriver driver;
 @BeforeMethod
 @Parameters("BROWSER")
 public void init(@Optional("Chrome")String BROWSER) throws Exception{
  System.out.println("****** In Before Method init method *********");
  System.out.println("Driver instanceis created and  set current local thread");
  //Opening desired Browser driver instance
  driver=DriverFactory.OpenBrowser(BROWSER);
  //Setting Current driver with threadLocal
  Driver.setCurrentDriver(driver);
  Driver.getCurrentDriver().manage().window().maximize();
  Driver.getCurrentDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  //This is Baseclass constructor (Initializaton)
  new BaseClass(Driver.getCurrentDriver());
 }
 
 @Test(description="This is first test same as first ")
 public void LoginFunctionality() throws Exception{
  
  System.out.println("*********Running first Test Case *********");
  MercuryHomePage_Action.Login_Action();
  MercuryHomePage_Action.Register_Action();
  
  System.out.println("PASSED : First test case : Login Successful..");
  
 }
 
 @Test(description="This is second test same as first ")
 public void LoginFunctionality1() throws Exception{
  
  System.out.println("*********Running second Test Case *********");
  MercuryHomePage_Action.Login_Action();
  MercuryHomePage_Action.Register_Action();
  
  System.out.println("PASSED : second test case : Login Successful..");
  
 }
 
 @Test(description="This is third test same as first ")
 public void LoginFunctionality2() throws Exception{
  
  System.out.println("*********Running third  Test Case *********");
  MercuryHomePage_Action.Login_Action();
  MercuryHomePage_Action.Register_Action();
  
  System.out.println("PASSED : third test case : Login Successful..");
 }
 
 @AfterMethod
 public void teardown(){
  
  System.out.println("****** In After Method tear down *********");
  System.out.println("Removing driver instance from current thread and closing all sesions");
  //Driver.getCurrentDriver().quit();
  Driver.QuitDriver();
 }
 
 @AfterTest
 public void aftertest(){
  Driver.clearCurrentDriver();
 }
}
```

```html
Driver Factory Class:
public class DriverFactory {

 //private static WebDriver driver;

 //@Parameters("BROWSER")
 public static WebDriver OpenBrowser(String BROWSER) throws Exception{
   WebDriver driver=null;
  try{
   if(BROWSER.equals("Mozilla")){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Log.info("New driver instantiated");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Log.info("Implicit wait applied on the driver for 10 seconds");
    //driver.get(Constant.URL);
    Log.info("Web application launched successfully");
   }else if(BROWSER.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Afsar\\git\\HybridFramework_POM\\HybridFramework\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Log.info("New driver instantiated");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Log.info("Implicit wait applied on the driver for 10 seconds");
    //driver.get(Constant.URL);
    Log.info("Web application launched successfully");
   }
  }catch (Exception e){
   Log.error("Class Utils | Method OpenBrowser | Exception desc : "+e.getMessage());
  }
  return driver;
 }
```

```html
Driver class:

private static  ThreadLocal<WebDriver> CURRENT_DRIVER = new ThreadLocal<>();

 public static WebDriver getCurrentDriver() {
  System.out.println("Get curent thread method is called .."); 
  Long callingThreadID = new Long(Thread.currentThread().getId());
  System.out.println("Current thread id :"+callingThreadID +" thread name is :"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
  return CURRENT_DRIVER.get();
 }

 public static void setCurrentDriver(WebDriver driver) {
  System.out.println("Set current thread method is called ..");
  CURRENT_DRIVER.set(driver);
 }

 public static void clearCurrentDriver() {
  
  System.out.println("Current thread removed and clearcurrentDriver() called.. ..");
  if (CURRENT_DRIVER.get() != null) {
   CURRENT_DRIVER.get().quit();
   CURRENT_DRIVER.remove();
        }
  
  CURRENT_DRIVER.remove();
 }
 
 public static void QuitDriver() {
  
  System.out.println("driver.quite called ");
  if (CURRENT_DRIVER.get() != null) {
   CURRENT_DRIVER.get().quit();
   //CURRENT_DRIVER.remove();
        }
  
  //CURRENT_DRIVER.remove();
 }
```

*Please help me in this scenario ,you can find this project in the GitHub repository :
https://github.com/afsarali273/HybridFramework_POM *

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that, driver.quit() is called when your first test is run because in After method annotation, driver.quit() was called after first test case. In that way, driver is null for second and third test case.Use the following code below. It will work fine :)

```
@AfterMethod
public void teardown(){         
    System.out.println("****** In After Method tear down *********");
    System.out.println("Removing driver instance from current thread and closing all sesions");
    //Driver.getCurrentDriver().quit();         
}

@AfterTest
    public void aftertest(){
    Driver.QuitDriver();
}
```

Comment: ..my intention is to run tests parallely  with grid...hence after each test need to quit driver instance in @ AfterMethod , Could you please look into my codes given in the GitHub ...Thanks

Comment: And it should be thread safe ...using Local thread<webdriver>

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is arising from

```java
@AfterTest
public void aftertest(){
    Driver.clearCurrentDriver();
}
```

You are invoking `quit()` on a driver instance for which `quit()` has already been invoked. You can get rid of the `@AfterTest` method and you should be fine after that.

**Update:**
After looking at the source code from the github repository that was shared, I noticed multiple issues. Calling out the two major ones.

1. All the classes seem to be sharing a common static webdriver instance in `com.afsar.framework.BaseClass#driver`. This defeats the entire point of working with `ThreadLocal`. Please have this changed.
2. There are static methods such as `com.afsar.framework.actions.MercuryHomePage_Action#Login_Action` which seem to be working with again a static instance of a page. It should be changed to something like a factory method, which when invoked would create a new instance of `MercuryHomePage_Action` and `Login_Action` method would just work as an instance method.

Comment: i removed Driver.clearCurrentDriver();from @ 
 Aftertest  ..but still getting same error ,could you please suggest me some other alternatives (Is this isuue related to Static webdriver instance used in BaseClass ??)

Comment: Hi Krishnan, could you please suggest me with example...shall I call driver.get() in base class ...instead of parameterizing constructor in the login class.

Comment: Or you could contribute in the GitHub .. Please

Comment: In terms of working with thread local webdriver instances, you can refer to [my](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/) blog post . Not sure what additional example you are looking for.